# How do I get a nicer Lambda?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

In computer science, the use of

[image]

as the letter lambda is quite recognisable as a symbol. How can I get this in LaTeX without changing the entire font of the document/math mode? I only want to change my lambdas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: Use `txfonts` package `\lambdaup`.  See also [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) for using just this symbol.

Comment: @AlanMunn It is not really a duplicate of that. It is a duplicate of that in combination with that other question about using a single symbol. But I don't know you can mark as duplicate of a combination....

Comment: @AlanMunn I see you edited while I wrote that... Indeed. ;)

Comment: @cfr I also retracted my close vote for that reason. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I didn't manage to understand how I could implement the solutions on that post to my problem - didn't fully get the syntax.

Comment: @AlanMunn How do you do that? Retract a close vote, I mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining [Alan Munn's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290165/how-do-i-get-a-nicer-lambda?noredirect=1#comment702120_290165) with [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/):

```
\documentclass{article}
% ref.: egreg at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Pimathsymbol[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\@Pimathsymbol{#2}{#3}}}
\def\@Pimathsymbol#1#2{\mathchoice
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\sf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\ssf@size}}
\def\@Pim@thsymbol#1#2#3{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#3}{#3}\Pisymbol{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother
% the next two lines are needed to avoid LaTeX substituting upright from another font
\input{utxmia.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{txmia}{m}{n}{<->ssub * txmia/m/it}{}
% you may also want
\DeclareFontShape{U}{txmia}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * txmia/bx/it}{}
% just in case
%\DeclareFontShape{U}{txmia}{l}{n}{<->ssub * txmia/l/it}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{U}{txmia}{b}{n}{<->ssub * txmia/b/it}{}
% plus info from Alan Munn at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290165/how-do-i-get-a-nicer-lambda?noredirect=1#comment702120_290165
\newcommand{\pilambdaup}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathord]{txmia}{21}}
\begin{document}
$\pilambdaup$
\end{document}
```