# How do I get a nicer slanted Lambda?

Tags: symbols, greek, slanted

I am trying to get a slanted version of the more "typical" lambda symbol:

[image]

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290165/how-do-i-get-a-nicer-lambda) post was very helpful to substitute only this particular symbol. My only issue is having it slanted...

Comment: Could italic be accepted as slanted?  https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsartemisia/doc/ArtemisiaSpecimen.pdf

Comment: See also http://ctan.javinator9889.com/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsneohellenic/doc/NeohellenicSpecimen.pdf

Comment: And the CB-Fonts  (cbgreek or cbfonts) have slanted version: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/fonts/greek/cbfonts/cbgreek.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I don't really see a character that looks like the one above but slanted. I am not sure I full understand the approach from @cfr here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290165/how-do-i-get-a-nicer-lambda  but he substitutes from txmia(?) Are there slanted characters in txmia?

Answer (score 1):

The glyph in the TX fonts is essentially the same as in Adobe Symbol. In TeX Live (but I believe also in MiKTeX), the slanted version is available as `psyro`. All it takes is to find the right slot, which turns out to be `"6C`.

I added also the upright version for comparison.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Pimathsymbol[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\@Pimathsymbol{#2}{#3}}}
\def\@Pimathsymbol#1#2{\mathchoice
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\sf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\ssf@size}}
\def\@Pim@thsymbol#1#2#3{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#3}{#3}\Pisymbol{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother

% the upright lambda
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{psyr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{psyr}{m}{n}{<-> psyr }{}
\newcommand{\pilambdaup}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathord]{psyr}{"6C}}
% the slanted lambda
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{psyro}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{psyro}{m}{n}{<-> psyro }{}
\newcommand{\pilambdait}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathord]{psyro}{"6C}}

\begin{document}

$\pilambdaup\ne\pilambdait$

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I do not find the glyph particularly attractive, nor “more typical”: any “lambda” glyph will convey the same idea.

Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290171/4427 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/4427

Comment: Thanks! This looks exactly like what I am looking for! But for some reason I get different symbols (see link, left for upright, right for italics) [link](https://ibb.co/QHgrbZG)

Comment: BTW, I agree that any lambda would convey the same idea. Though, my document strongly refers to a regulatory framework with extensive documentation and reporting and I would really like to stick with the stylistic "rules" and decisions taken there. For consistency.

Comment: Ok, my wrong! My editor replaced " with two single '... It works!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you can substitute this glyph from a different font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=\mitlambda,Scale=MatchLowercase]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ \lambda \]
\end{document}
```

[image: XITS Math sample]